# Javascript loads first even though code at the end of <body> tag

Tags: javascript, html

I have added external Javascript at the end of  tag in HTML file however, the alert loads first and only on hitting the "Okay" button on alert, the content loads up. Below is my HTML and JS code.

*I already tried putting the script in the  and async/defer thing too.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>My Website</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Hello</h1>

    <script src="index.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

---

```
JS

alert("Hello");
```

Comment: We cannot see the JavaScript code :) Please add it again

Comment: you can verify in the network tab the the html is loaded with the first request! nevertheless the alert is obviously parsed faster than _rendering_ the html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the DOM parsing normally happens on the main thread. So if the main JavaScript execution thread is busy, DOM parsing will not progress until the thread is free.

If the script element is an external script file, the browser will start the download of the external script file off the main thread but it will halt the execution of the main thread until that file is downloaded. That means no more DOM parsing until the script file is downloaded.

You should learn about the steps that happen when a website gets loaded/parsed/rendered

Taken from: [https://medium.com/jspoint/how-the-browser-renders-a-web-page-dom-cssom-and-rendering-df10531c9969#:~:text=When%20a%20web%20page%20is,the%20Render%2DTree%20from%20it](https://medium.com/jspoint/how-the-browser-renders-a-web-page-dom-cssom-and-rendering-df10531c9969#:%7E:text=When%20a%20web%20page%20is,the%20Render%2DTree%20from%20it).

if you would not have used alert() function, you wouldnt even notice that, but special to alert is that it stops all further execution until you confirmed the alert, regarding the written above, this explains why the page renders after confirming the alert

Answer (score 2):

`alert` is a synchronous function.
Note that putting the script at the end of the body only means it will be run when the page is **parsed** and not when the content is shown. The content is only shown afterwards
Because `alert` is synchronous, it will run first before then showing the content.

Comment: I think you mean "synchronous". `alert` is very much _not_ asynchronous.

Answer (score 1):

You could try putting whatever logic you are doing on the `onload` event of the `window` like so:

```js
window.onload = () => {
  // logic goes here
  console.log('the document has been loaded');
};
```

Answer (score -1):

Javascript has an asynchonous behaviour. If you want ensure dom loaded before do anything consider use Jquery

https://jquery.com/

before place your Jquery library into your js code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

//... all your's stuffs here

});
```

**A PRO TIP:** Learn Jquery will lead you create amazing things!!
Best regards

Comment: Sorry, -1. jQuery can be a resource hog especially for a simple problem like this.

Comment: Hey guy i dont think so he will build an simpliest application like this. Ball out ;)

Comment: oops can't revoke

Comment: @expressjs123 no problem :D May this answer will make sense to others and present amazing Jquery